# Accessing Variable-Values from Complex Lists of Nested Map Objects in Flutter

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, flutter, nested-lists

I'm receiving a response from a server-call, which I've decoded from JSON into a List

Now any of the level 1 list-values I can access, no issues.  However, *some* of the values I'm receiving are complex, instead of a simple data-type like a String or an int, it is a Map object, with nested variables inside.

How do I get access to those?

I can't create a class to parse the Map objects into, because they could be of many different kinds, and there's no way for me to understand what they will be in advance.

Examples of a server response I *could* receive:

```
[{
  info1: something,
  info2: something else,
  info3: something something else,
  info4: [{
    object1: data,
    object2: data2,
    object3: data3
  }],
  info5: something something something else,
}]
```

At the same time, I cannot know in advance whether or not I will be receiving a response at any given point that will contain such a map object, or which kind it will be. So how do I get access to those variables? Right now, if I type

```
print(list[0][info4]);
```

I would get

```
[{object1: data, object2: data2, object3: data3}]
```

From there, what I need to be able to do, is get the individual variable data, e.g. for object1 inside info4

```
data
```

So I *have* the data, but after getting the individual index, how to I access the data inside that object? What notation do I use? Everything I've tried either returns null, or type errors.

Also, the line of code I'm using to decode the server response is as follows.

```
List<dynamic> data2 = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

So the data is currently in the format of List and if I need to use some other line to decode it into a different format, or something, that might give you an idea where I'm starting from.

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] of the null returns and/or type errors?

Comment: please post your real full json response and ping my name, thanks.

Comment: @chunhunghan I cannot post the full real json due to an NDA.  So that is physically not possible.  I apologize for the inconvenience, but that is why I included an example-version which contains as much pertinent information as is needed to be able to answer the question.  As it's only the nested variable values I cannot access.

Comment: @jonrsharpe An example of a null return would be list[0][info4][object1], if I instead tried to print via dot-notation, like list[0][info4].object1 I would not even get a response on my debug console, it would just skip that line entirely.  So no error-message I could use to google.  Or else I would have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha!  Managed to figure it out.  It's actually because of the brackets, and bracket-types.

Effectively, the [ bracket denotes a List, whereas the { bracket denotes a Map.  I didn't understand this going in, so the notations I was using were confusing.

Now that I understand that, The notation works.

So in the above example, the method I would use to get access the to object1: data result, would be as follows.

```
 print(info[0][info4][0][object1]);
```

So in essence, due to the [] brackets, it's asking for an integer case to identify a given object, whereas the {} brackets are asking for a String case to identify to object instead.  Once I understand this, the rest came automatically, and I was able to resolve the parsing of the data as needed.

Thank you for your insightful comments though!